# Maximum values series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm struggling with the problem of showing additional serie that will contains maximum values for every x. Like this:

[image: Expected result]

I was able to parse all series to aggregate points and also found cross points to include them. Currently I have a problem with cross point (A) that are below one of the series. (Solution A in fiddle)I was thinking about calculating line and check if the point A belongs to that line. This will fix scenario but will cause problem for point B bc it doesn't belong to calculated line but should be included in serie.

Could any one point me to the right direction?

```js
    var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
             type: 'area',
             zoomType: 'x',
                    backgroundColor:null,
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime',
           dateTimeLabelFormats: {
             month: '%b %e',
             year: '%b'
           },
         },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            }
          }
        }
    });
    
    chart.addSeries({"id":0,"connectNulls":true,"data":[[1524469020000,30],[1524469080000,30],[1524469140000,30],[1524469200000,30],[1524469260000,30],[1524469320000,30],[1524469380000,30],[1524469440000,30],[1524469500000,30],[1524469560000,58],[1524469620000,4],[1524469680000,4],[1524469740000,4],[1524469800000,4],[1524469860000,4],[1524469920000,4],[1524469980000,4],[1524470040000,4],[1524470100000,4],[1524470160000,4],[1524470220000,4],[1524470280000,4],[1524470340000,4],[1524470400000,4],[1524470460000,4],[1524470520000,22],[1524470580000,22],[1524470640000,22],[1524470700000,22]],"name":"Serie A","color":"#30e430","yAxis":0});
    
    chart.addSeries({"id":1,"connectNulls":true,"data":[[1524469020000,35],[1524469080000,35],[1524469140000,35],[1524469200000,35],[1524469260000,35],[1524469320000,35],[1524469380000,35],[1524469440000,35],[1524469500000,35],[1524469560000,25],[1524469620000,25],[1524469680000,25],[1524469740000,25],[1524469800000,25],[1524469860000,25],[1524469920000,25],[1524469980000,59],[1524470040000,59],[1524470100000,59],[1524470160000,59],[1524470220000,59],[1524470280000,59],[1524470340000,59],[1524470400000,59],[1524470460000,59],[1524470520000,59],[1524470580000,59],[1524470640000,59],[1524470700000,59]],"name":"Serie B","color":"#0cb5ed","yAxis":0});
    
    chart.addSeries({"id":2,"connectNulls":true,"data":[[1524469020000,18],[1524469080000,18],[1524469140000,18],[1524469200000,18],[1524469260000,18],[1524469320000,18],[1524469380000,18],[1524469440000,18],[1524469500000,18],[1524469560000,18],[1524469620000,18],[1524469680000,18],[1524469740000,18],[1524469800000,18],[1524469860000,18],[1524469920000,18],[1524469980000,18],[1524470040000,18],[1524470100000,18],[1524470160000,18],[1524470220000,18],[1524470280000,18],[1524470340000,18],[1524470400000,18],[1524470460000,18],[1524470520000,18],[1524470580000,18],[1524470640000,18],[1524470700000,18]],"name":"Serie C","color":"#e8ad23","yAxis":0});
    
    $('#button').click(function () {
      var results = getChartPointValues();
    
      var data = prepareSummarySeries(results);
     
      //clean previously added virutal series
      for(var i in chart.series){
        var serie = chart.series[i];
    
        if(serie.userOptions.is_virtual == true)
          serie.remove();
      }
    
      chart.addSeries({
        id: 'virtual_max_b',
        is_virtual: true,
        'connectNulls': true,
        'data' : data.max_b,
        'name' : 'Solution A',
        'color' : '#000',
        'yAxis': 0,
      });
      chart.addSeries({
        id: 'virtual_max_a',
        is_virtual: true,
        'connectNulls': true,
        'data' : data.max_a,
        'name' : 'Base Solution',
        'color' : '#ff0000',
        'yAxis': 0,
      });
    });
    /*
    * Calculate max values for every point
    */
    var prepareSummarySeries = function(data){
     var tmp_keys = Object.keys(data); ///sort
      tmp_keys = tmp_keys.sort();
      var counter = tmp_keys.length;
      var results = {
       'max_a': [],
        'max_b': [],
      };
       for(var k = 0; k < counter; k++){
         var key = tmp_keys[k];
         var x_pos = parseFloat(key);
         
         if(x_pos % 1 !== 0)
         {
           var prev_point    = results.max_b.slice(-1)[0];
           var current_point = [x_pos, data[key][0]];
           var next_point    = [ parseFloat(tmp_keys[k+1]), Math.max.apply(null, data[tmp_keys[k+1]] )];
    
           if( checkIfPointBelongsToChart(prev_point, current_point, next_point) ){
             results.max_b.push([ x_pos, current_point[1] ]);
           }
         } else {
           results.max_b.push([ x_pos, Math.max.apply(null, data[key]) ]);
         }
        
         
         
         results.max_a.push([ x_pos, Math.max.apply(null, data[key]) ]);
      }
      
      return results;
    };
    
    
    var get_line_intersection = function(p0,p1,p2,p3){
      var p0_x = p0.x;
      var p0_y = p0.y;
      var p1_x = p1.x;
      var p1_y = p1.y;
      var p2_x = p2.x;
      var p2_y = p2.y;
      var p3_x = p3.x;
      var p3_y = p3.y;
    
      var s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
      s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;     s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
      s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;     s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;
    
      var s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
      var t = ( s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    
      if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
      {
        return [p0_x + (t * s1_x),p0_y + (t * s1_y)];
      }
    
      return false;
    };
    
    var checkIfPointBelongsToChart = function(prev_point, current_point, next_point)
    {
      var slope = (next_point[1] - prev_point[1]) / (next_point[0] - prev_point[0]);
      var b = prev_point[1] - slope * prev_point[0];
    
      var tmp_y = slope * current_point[0] + b;
    
      return (tmp_y == current_point[1])? true : false;
    };
    
    // create array with every x point with every possible y value
    // im not taking only max here bc later we could need min instead of max
    var getChartPointValues = function(){
      var results = {}
      var self = this;
      var points = [];
    
      var checked_series = [];
      for(var k =0; k < chart.series.length; k++)
      {
        var entry = chart.series[k];
    
        if(entry.userOptions.is_virtual == true || entry.visible == false)
          continue;
    
        var s1_points = entry.data;
        var c1 = s1_points.length;
    
    
        //add all points from serie
        for(var i = 0; i < c1; i++)
        {
          if(s1_points[i] == undefined || !s1_points[i].isInside)
            continue;
    
          if(points[s1_points[i].x] == undefined){
            points[s1_points[i].x] = [];
          }
    
          points[s1_points[i].x].push(s1_points[i].y);
        }
    
    
        //check all points in all charts for crossing points
        for(var s in chart.series){
          var serie = chart.series[s];
    
          if(serie.userOptions.is_virtual == true || serie.visible == false)
            continue;
    
          //skip serie if combination of series was already checked
          var current_check = entry.userOptions.id + '_' + serie.userOptions.id;
          if(checked_series.indexOf(current_check) != -1 || serie.userOptions.is_virtual == true)
            continue;
    
          checked_series.push(current_check);
          checked_series.push(serie.userOptions.id + '_' + entry.userOptions.id);
    
          if(serie.index != entry.index){
            var s2_points = serie.data;
            var c2 = s2_points.length;
    
            for(var i = 0; i < c1; i++)
            {
              if(s1_points[i] == undefined || !s1_points[i].isInside)
                continue;
    
              for(var j = 0; j < c2; j++)
              {
                if(s2_points[j] == undefined || !s2_points[j].isInside)
                  continue;
    
                var cross = [];
                if(s1_points[i-1] != undefined && s2_points[j-1] != undefined){
                  if(cross = get_line_intersection(s1_points[i-1], s1_points[i], s2_points[j-1], s2_points[j])){
                    if(points[cross[0]] == undefined){
                      points[cross[0]] = [];
                    }
    
                    points[cross[0]].push(cross[1])
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    
      return points;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<button id="button">Add Maximum series</button>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3koe86sx/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to solve this using a slightly different method. The gist of it is:

1. Find the series that has the max point
2. Find the series that has the next max point
3. Check if there is an intersect between the lines of these two series
4. If there is an intersect, add that as a separate point
5. Add the next max point

There is one caveat with doing it like this, a sparse series has the ability to ruin the graph, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/3koe86sx/15/
Solving that issue would be tedious, requiring you to find all x points, and for lines without all points present, fill in their values.

That being said, as long as the series have roughly the same number of points, this should work well.

```js
var get_line_intersection = function(p0, p1, p2, p3) {
  var p0_x = p0.x;
  var p0_y = p0.y;
  var p1_x = p1.x;
  var p1_y = p1.y;
  var p2_x = p2.x;
  var p2_y = p2.y;
  var p3_x = p3.x;
  var p3_y = p3.y;

  var s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
  s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;
  s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
  s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;
  s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

  var s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
  var t = (s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

  if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
    return [p0_x + (t * s1_x), p0_y + (t * s1_y)];
  }

  return false;
};

//Gets the next point
function getNextPoint(series, current_x, current_y) {
  nextPoint = {
    next_x: 0,
    next_y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: -1,
    prev_x: 0,
    prev_y: 0
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < series[i].length; j++) {
      if (series[i][j].x > current_x) { //Goes one step past current timestamp
        if (series[i][j].y > nextPoint.y || nextPoint.y == -1) { //Checks that this is the max number, could be changed to find min as well
          if (j < series[i].length - 1) { //Checks if this is the last point (to avoid going past last index)
            nextPoint = {
              next_x: series[i][j + 1].x,
              next_y: series[i][j + 1].y,
              x: series[i][j].x,
              y: series[i][j].y,
              prev_x: series[i][j - 1].x,
              prev_y: series[i][j - 1].y,
            }
          } else {
            nextPoint = {
              x: series[i][j].x,
              y: series[i][j].y,
              prev_x: series[i][j - 1].x,
              prev_y: series[i][j - 1].y,
            }
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return nextPoint
}

function getAllSeries(chart) {
  var allSeries = []
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
    allSeries.push(chart.series[i].data)
  }
  return allSeries
}


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    zoomType: 'x',
    backgroundColor: null,
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      month: '%b %e',
      year: '%b'
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      fillOpacity: 0.1,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
});

chart.addSeries({
  "id": 0,
  "connectNulls": true,
  "data": [
    [1524469020000, 30],
    [1524469080000, 30],
    [1524469140000, 30],
    [1524469200000, 30],
    [1524469260000, 30],
    [1524469320000, 30],
    [1524469380000, 30],
    [1524469440000, 30],
    [1524469500000, 30],
    [1524469560000, 58],
    [1524469620000, 4],
    [1524469680000, 4],
    [1524469740000, 4],
    [1524469800000, 4],
    [1524469860000, 4],
    [1524469920000, 4],
    [1524469980000, 4],
    [1524470040000, 4],
    [1524470100000, 4],
    [1524470160000, 4],
    [1524470220000, 4],
    [1524470280000, 4],
    [1524470340000, 4],
    [1524470400000, 4],
    [1524470460000, 4],
    [1524470520000, 22],
    [1524470580000, 22],
    [1524470640000, 22],
    [1524470700000, 22]
  ],
  "name": "Serie A",
  "color": "#30e430",
  "yAxis": 0
});

chart.addSeries({
  "id": 1,
  "connectNulls": true,
  "data": [
    [1524469020000, 35],
    [1524469080000, 35],
    [1524469140000, 35],
    [1524469200000, 35],
    [1524469260000, 35],
    [1524469320000, 35],
    [1524469380000, 35],
    [1524469440000, 35],
    [1524469500000, 35],
    [1524469560000, 25],
    [1524469620000, 25],
    [1524469680000, 25],
    [1524469740000, 25],
    [1524469800000, 25],
    [1524469860000, 25],
    [1524469920000, 25],
    [1524469980000, 59],
    [1524470040000, 59],
    [1524470100000, 59],
    [1524470160000, 59],
    [1524470220000, 59],
    [1524470280000, 59],
    [1524470340000, 59],
    [1524470400000, 59],
    [1524470460000, 59],
    [1524470520000, 59],
    [1524470580000, 59],
    [1524470640000, 59],
    [1524470700000, 59]
  ],
  "name": "Serie B",
  "color": "#0cb5ed",
  "yAxis": 0
});

chart.addSeries({
  "id": 2,
  "connectNulls": true,
  "data": [
    [1524469020000, 18],
    [1524469080000, 18],
    [1524469140000, 18],
    [1524469200000, 18],
    [1524469260000, 18],
    [1524469320000, 18],
    [1524469380000, 18],
    [1524469440000, 18],
    [1524469500000, 18],
    [1524469560000, 18],
    [1524469620000, 18],
    [1524469680000, 18],
    [1524469740000, 18],
    [1524469800000, 18],
    [1524469860000, 18],
    [1524469920000, 18],
    [1524469980000, 18],
    [1524470040000, 18],
    [1524470100000, 18],
    [1524470130000, 80],
    [1524470160000, 18],
    [1524470220000, 18],
    [1524470280000, 18],
    [1524470340000, 18],
    [1524470400000, 18],
    [1524470460000, 18],
    [1524470520000, 18],
    [1524470580000, 18],
    [1524470640000, 18],
    [1524470700000, 18]
  ],
  "name": "Serie C",
  "color": "#e8ad23",
  "yAxis": 0
});



$('#button').click(function() {
  series = getAllSeries(chart)

  var currentPoint = {
    next_x: 0,
    next_y: 0,
    x: -1,
    y: 0,
    prev_x: 0,
    prev_y: 0
  }
  var max_x = 0;

  //finds the first point
  for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    if (currentPoint.y < series[i][0].y || currentPoint.x == -1) { //makes sure this is the largest point
      currentPoint = {
        prev_x: series[i][0].x,
        prev_y: series[i][0].y,
        x: series[i][0].x,
        y: series[i][0].y,
        next_x: series[i][1].x,
        next_y: series[i][1].y
      }
    }
    if (max_x < series[i][series[i].length - 1].x) {
      max_x = series[i][series[i].length - 1].x;
    }
  }


  result = []
  result.push({ //since the first point comes from the above code, we need to add it explicitly
    x: currentPoint.x,
    y: currentPoint.y
  })
  while (currentPoint.x != max_x) { //loop through all points
    nextPoint = getNextPoint(series, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    let intersect = get_line_intersection({
      x: nextPoint.prev_x,
      y: nextPoint.prev_y
    }, {
      x: nextPoint.x,
      y: nextPoint.y
    }, {
      x: currentPoint.x,
      y: currentPoint.y
    }, {
      x: currentPoint.next_x,
      y: currentPoint.next_y
    })
    if (intersect != false) { //if there is an intersect point, make sure to add it
      result.push({
        x: intersect[0],
        y: intersect[1]
      })
    }
    result.push({
      x: nextPoint.x,
      y: nextPoint.y
    });
    currentPoint = nextPoint
  }
  chart.addSeries({
    name: 'Max Points',
    lineColor: 'red',
    //dashStyle: 'LongDash',
    data: result
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<button id="button">Add Maximum series</button>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**jsfiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/3koe86sx/14/

Comment: If this is not what you were after, let me know and I will delete my answer.